# Animating back to the original position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, positioning

I want to animate the image which is clicked by the user to the top left 100x100 then I want it to return to its original position where the animation started but with this piece of code it keeps sliding by some pixels to the top and left.  I couldn't figure out what causes this problem.  How can I make it return to its original position?

```
var posLeft;
var posTop;

$(this).children("img").click(function() {


        goToTopLeft($(this));

        $.each($(this).parent().children("img"), function() {

            $(this).css("z-index","0");

        });

        goToFrontFromTopLeft($(this));

        $(this).css("z-index", "1");



    });

function goToTopLeft(img) {
        posLeft = img.position().left;
        posTop = img.position().top;
        img.animate({ top: '-=100', left: '-=100', height: 'toggle' }, 500);
    }

    function goToFrontFromTopLeft(img) {
        img.animate({ top: posTop, left: posLeft, height: 'toggle' }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: can you post your HTML too, and maybe a live example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm animating from, and to, a different position than yourself, the following code should give you an idea how to do what you're trying to do:

```
$('img').click(
    function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var originLeft = offset.left;
        var originTop = offset.top;
        $(this).animate(
            {
                'top' : '400px',
                'left': '200px'
            }, 1500, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    'top': originTop,
                    'left' : originLeft
            }, 1500)
                    });

    });
```

[Link to JS Fiddle Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FhC3r/).

I'll note that, in my first attempt, my own animation *also* had a momentary flicker which seems to be due to the container element having a padding, or margin, which is why the CSS pane on that page contains the following:

```
body, div, iframe {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This seems to have cured that momentary 'flicker,' and, I suspect, would likely cure your own issue. But without seeing a live demo it's incredibly hard to know what the problem is, besides guessing. If this doesn't help I'd certainly recommend posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo so that we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I removed the functions and added their contents to the each funtion and it works!

Comment: @Sarpdoruk: you're absolutely welcome; if I provided any assistance, feel free to up-vote =p

Comment: Wish I could but don't have enough reputaion :/

Comment: @Sarpdoruk: ah...I'd always assumed folks were free to up-vote answers to their own questions from the get-go. I may have been here before such actions were capped, or just forgot about it... =)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the `img` you're animating is positioned absolutely?  I was able to reproduce this issue with an absolutely positioned `img`.  If you position the image relatively, I believe this will fix your problem.  I set up a simplified example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/fj787/).  Try changing the CSS to `position:absolute` and you'll see the issue.

I'm not sure *why* jQuery won't respect the inline style of the element in combination with the `toggle` option for height, maybe others can chime in about that.

Comment: Actually I am using    position:absolute    to put all images on one another.  Removing those functions    goToTopLeft    and    goToFrontFromTopLeft    and adding contents of those into the each function worked out for me.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns all animated styles to starter position/style

```
var animate = function(selector, obj) {
    var original = {};
    if (!$(selector).is(":animated")) {
        $.each(obj, function(i, v) {
            original[i] = $(selector).css(i);
        });
        $(selector).animate(obj, function() {
            $(selector).animate(original);
        })
    }
}
```